# Custom generator runs out of data even when steps_per_epoch specified

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am training a model using custom generators, but just before finishing the first epoch, the model runs out of data. It gives me the following error:

`Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least (steps_per_epoch * epochs) batches (in this case, 8740 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset`

I have four generators (one for the train data, and another for the train label. Same thing with validation). I then zip train & label together. This is the prototype of my generators. [I got the idea from here](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly):

```
import numpy as np
import nibabel as nib
from tensorflow import keras
import os

def weirddivision(n,d):
    return np.array(n)/np.array(d) if d else 0

class ImgDataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __init__(self, file_list, batch_size=8, shuffle=True):
        """Constructor can be expanded,
           with batch size, dimentation etc.
        """
        self.file_list = file_list
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()
        

    def __len__(self):
        'Take all batches in each iteration'
        return int(np.floor(len(self.file_list) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Get next batch'
        # Generate indexes of the batch
        indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

        # single file
        file_list_temp = [self.file_list[k] for k in indexes]

        # Set of X_train and y_train
        X = self.__data_generation(file_list_temp)

        return X

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.file_list))
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __data_generation(self, file_list_temp):
        'Generates data containing batch_size samples'
        train_loc = '/home/faruk/Desktop/BrainSeg/Dataset/Train/'
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size,224,256,1))
        # Generate data
        for i, ID in enumerate(file_list_temp):
            x_file_path = os.path.join(train_loc, ID)
            img = np.load(x_file_path)
            img = np.pad(img, pad_width=((14,13),(12,11)), mode='constant')
            img = np.expand_dims(img,-1)
            img = weirddivision(img, img.max())

            # Store sample
            X[i,] = img


        return X
```

As mentioned, here I create four generators and zip them:

```
training_img_generator = ImgDataGenerator(train)
training_label_generator = LabelDataGenerator(train)
train_generator = zip(training_img_generator,training_label_generator)

val_img_generator = ValDataGenerator(val)
val_label_generator = ValLabelDataGenerator(val)
val_generator = zip(val_img_generator,val_label_generator)
```

Because the generator is generating data dynamically, I thought that maybe it was trying to generate more than what is actually available. Hence, I calculated the steps per epoch as follows and passed it to fit_generator:

```
batch_size = 8
spe = len(train)//batch_size # len(train) = 34965
val_spe = len(val)//batch_size # len(val) = 4347

History=model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator, validation_data=val_generator, epochs=2, steps_per_epoch=spe, validation_steps = val_spe, shuffle=True, verbose=1)
```

But still, this is not working. I have tried reducing the number of steps per epoch, and I am able to finish the first epoch, but the error then appears at the beginning of the second epoch. Apparently the generator needs to be repeated infinitely, but I don't know how to achieve this. Can I use an infinite while loop? If yes, where?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
train_generator = train_generator.repeat()
val_generator = val_generator.repeat()
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I tried that, but it gives me the following error: `'zip' object has no attribute 'repeat'`  I think that's happening because .repeat() can only be called if the object is of type tf.data

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. I was defining my Generator class as follows:

```
class ImgDataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence)
```

However, my model was not sequential... It was functional. I solved this by creating my own custom generator without inheriting from the keras.utils.sequence.

I hope this is helpful to someone.